# Does google index script tags as content when using handlebars.js

Tags: seo, handlebars.js, script-tag

If you use the standard handlesbar.js [implementation](http://handlebarsjs.com/), does Google view the content within the custom script tags as content, script or unknown content?

Comment: Interesting question.  My guess is only Google knows.  They may try to do some analysis to see if they recognize any structure to it, but if they are templates and such, I feel like they would ignore it.  They could execute script in their crawler and look for content after onload also.

Comment: Logically, it would seem normal to ignore script tag contents, and similarly for style tags, but given that scope is available in style tags soon, it's not clear how this would be considered by a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're in doubt, do in pure HTML**. Unfortunately, Google should ignore this. I looked about, and all I heard is that this application was not made ​​to be searchfriendly.

In fact, Google undestand and even follow links created via Javascript, but handlebarsjs is very more complex.

### Possible solution

A strong suggestion that I make to you is load a simplified version with some content in plain simplified and after use handlebarsjs, so at then at least do not let google completely blind. But thsi version should be used also to end user, because google Will know if you show a diferent content just for Googlebot.

### Possible solution 2

Exist a way to make websites that rely heavily on AJAX still work in [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

Comment: My intention was to use client-side templates to reduce the data transfer, but the data itself would come from the server - perhaps in a crawlable way, but I was more interested in what google would see and if it would index all the extra template text as page content, which would potentially affect context.

Comment: So, please look at "possible solution 2". This way can be better than the fist one to your question, and heve good documentation here https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: Crawlable applications wouldn't solve the problem.  I'm actually trying to remove content from google visibility not include it.

Comment: Well, with "Possible Solution 2", if you just set via robots.txt, HTTP header or in HTML, you can also set "noindex, nofollow". Too much work, but for sure it works if you're in doubt.

Comment: The point is the code is IN THE PAGE not loaded in afterwards.  In that case, you can see the solutions above don't address the issue.